# Google Chrome extensions for the Mac?

Tags: macos, mac, google-chrome, browser-addons, development

Is it possible to use extensions on the developer build of Google Chrome for Mac? Ive seen tutorials for windows and linux.

Answer (score 4):

At this exact moment, you need a trunk build. You can get one here:
http://build.chromium.org/buildbot/snapshots/chromium-rel-mac/

We hope to turn extension support back on in the next dev channel release of Google Chrome for mac.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this: [Enable extensions in Chromium (or Chrome) - Mac OS X Hints](http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20091118063639927)

I would also look here for more information: [Chromium-extensions](http://groups.google.com/group/chromium-extensions?hl=)

Answer (score 0):

For reference the current version of Chrome supports extensions and has since February 2010.